# XIAO BLE with MAX30100 and BLE

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy

When I run MAX30100 by itself on SEEED XIAO BLE SENSE module everything works fine. But when I add BLE into code, MAX30100 stops getting beats when BLE begins. I am guessing this is to do with pox.update() not updating in time. If someone has any idea what I can do please share. Thank you.

My code is here:

```
//MAX30100 BPM + SPO2 header
#include <MAX30100_PulseOximeter.h>

//BLE header
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ArduinoBLE.h>

//Communication header
#include <Wire.h>

//MAX30100
PulseOximeter pox;
uint8_t hearty = 0;
uint8_t oxy = 0;

//MAX timer
unsigned long max_prev_millis = 0;

//BLE timer
unsigned long ble_prev_millis = 0;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(115200);

  if (!pox.begin()) Serial.println(F("MAX30100 error"));
  else Serial.println(F("MAX30100 OK!"));

  pox.setOnBeatDetectedCallback(onBeatDetected);
  
  // setting the registers for the bluetooth transmit power
  uint32_t *TXPOWER = (uint32_t *)0x4000150C;
  *TXPOWER &= 0x0;
  *TXPOWER |= 0x08;

  uint32_t *MODE = (uint32_t *)0x40001510;
  *MODE &= 0x0;
  *MODE |= 0x05;
  
  BLE.setLocalName("IT'S ME, BLE");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  pox.update();
  //Heart rate reading every 1 second
  if (millis() - max_prev_millis >= 1000){
      readMax30100();
  }

  //Bluetooth upload every 15 seconds
  if (millis() - ble_prev_millis >= 15 * 1000) {
      BLEUpload();
  }
}

void readMax30100(){
    hearty = pox.getHeartRate();
    oxy = pox.getSpO2();
  
    Serial.print(F("Heart rate:"));
    Serial.print(hearty);
    Serial.print(F("bpm / SpO2:"));
    Serial.print(oxy);
    Serial.println(F("%"));

    max_prev_millis = millis();
}

void BLEUpload(){
    BLE.begin();
    BLE.stopAdvertise();
    BLEAdvertisingData advData;
    advData.setFlags(BLEFlagsBREDRNotSupported | BLEFlagsGeneralDiscoverable);

    unsigned char send_data[2]
    {
      (unsigned char) (hearty),
      (unsigned char) (oxy)
    };
    
    advData.setAdvertisedServiceData(0x2ACA, send_data, sizeof(send_data));
    BLE.setAdvertisingData(advData);
    BLE.advertise();
    BLE.end();
    ble_prev_millis = millis();
}

void onBeatDetected(){
  Serial.println(F("Beat!"));
}
```

Comment: the pox.update() has to run at a minimum 100Hz i.e. cycle time of <10ms (and I believe the library set the sample frequency to 100Hz). It is likely that part of the `BLEUpload();` is blocking and taking longer than that, you might want to do some checking by capturing the millis() before and after to see which part causing it. I'm not familiar with BLE library so I can't comment more than that.

Comment: Seems like that was the issue. I ran pox.update() in a separate rtos thread and it uploads fine now. Cheers.